# No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mvc, simple-injector

Estou tentando criar um construtor com parâmetros, conforme mostrado abaixo:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAppService _servico;

    public DashboardController(IAppService servico)
    {
        _servico = servico;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var a = _servico.Pesquisar();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Foi feito a injeção de dependência, mas mesmo assim retorna o erro:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

```
   public static class SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer
{

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        InitializeContainer(container);

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.Verify();

        SimpleInjectorMvcExtensions.GetControllerTypesToRegister(container, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        Bootstrapper.Start(container);
    }
}
```

Já tentei diversas alternativas, porém sem sucesso. 
Saberiam me informar como posso resolver esse problema?

Grato desde já!

Comment: Como o próprio erro indica, precisa ter um construtor que não tenha parâmetros, por isso basta adicionar `public DashboardController() { }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou você registrar a injeção de dependência do `IAppService`, seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.AsyncScopedLifestyle();

    //Registra os services
    container.Register<IAppService, AppService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    InitializeContainer(container); 

    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    container.Verify();

    SimpleInjectorMvcExtensions.GetControllerTypesToRegister(container, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

Você pode ver mais na documentação deles: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 3):

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Ou seja, precisa ter um construtor sem parâmetros:

```
public DashboardController()
{
}
```

Isso não vai atrapalhar seu outro construtor com interface onde está injetando a dependência.